# PhoneGap shows only 30 contacts

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've used the right code to show the contacts. It works fine for the emulator but when I run it on the physical device it shows only some contacts. Around 20-30 only. How can I fix this error ? Here is my code :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {

     var options = new ContactFindOptions();
            var options = new ContactFindOptions();
            options.filter="";
            options.multiple=true; 
            var fields = ["*"];
            navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options,true);
}
function onSuccess(contacts) {
    alert("Total contacts = "+ contacts.length);
    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) 
    {
        // console.log("Display Name = " + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value);
        $('#contactList').append("<li><a href='#'><h2>"+ contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value +"</h2></a></li>");  
         $('#contactList').listview("refresh");

    }

}
function onError(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does it maybe matter if some contacts are sim contacts and some are stored on the phone?

Comment: Yup! It is. Then how can I get all the contacts ? @GreenBlueRup

Comment: Maybe this topic can help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373536/only-get-android-contacts-that-are-saved-to-the-phone-or-sim. I dont have an android setup to try for you at the moment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhoneGap retrieve contacts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905615/phonegap-retrieve-contacts)